# Why does Updated Session Info not access on Hangup call by using quickblox sdk from Website to Android?

Tags: php, android, quickblox

I am working on quickblox video calling, I am passing "name" as a key in userinfo from web when creating new session :

```
$(document).on('click', '.j-call', function(e) {

            var recp_login=$("#recipient_login").val();
            var recp_id=$("#recipient_id").val();

            var params = { 'login':'ravindra.gupta' , 'password': 'ravi@agicent'};

            QB.createSession(params, function(err, result) {
                if(!err){
                     var extension={
                            "userInfo": {
                               "coachname":app.caller.full_name,
                               "coachid":uid,
                               "coachimage":coachimg,
                               "message":app.caller.full_name + " is calling you"
                                }
                            };

                            app.currentSession.call(extension, function (error) {
                                if (error) {

                                    console.warn(error.detail);
                                } 
                }
            });
}
```

On android side I get the name from userinfo inside

```
public void onReceiveNewSession(final QBRTCSession session) {
        if (getCurrentSession() == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Start new session");

            session.getUserInfo().get("coachname");
        }

    }
```

When user closes (hangup) the call I am passing some more info ("state"), I use the following code:

```
/** Hangup */
        $(document).on('click', '.j-hangup', function() {
            if(!_.isEmpty(app.currentSession)) {
                var extension={
                    "userInfo": {
                        "state":'Paused'
                    }
                };

        app.currentSession.update(extension);
        app.currentSession.stop(extension,function(){});
                app.currentSession = {};
                $(".msg_board").show();
                qbApp.MsgBoard.update('call has pauzed');
            }
        });
```

But on android side inside onReceiveHangUpFromUser() function I am unable to get that new data ("state"), I get null all the time.

```
public void onReceiveHangUpFromUser(final QBRTCSession session,
            final Integer userID) {

        if (session.equals(getCurrentSession())) {

            String state = session.getUserInfo().get("state");
        }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

please, tell me, which version QuickBlox Android SDK do you use? This issue fixed in version 2.5.2

Comment: I am using QuickBlox SDK 2.5 for Android and QuickBlox JavaScript SDK - v1.17.0 for Web

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced QuickBlox Android SDk 2.5 with version 2.5.2.
Now its working fine and thank you @Valentyn Tereshchenko